# How long did Narasimha stay on earth?

Tags: narasimha

The AI bot Bard says

> There are different stories about how long Narasimha stayed on Earth after killing Hiranyakashipu. Some stories say that he stayed for a few days, while others say that he stayed for many years. In the end, he returned to the divine abode, but his story is still celebrated today in many Hindu temples.

> One story says that Narasimha stayed on Earth for 12 years, during which time he traveled through the jungles of Andhra Pradesh and fell in love with a local girl named Chenchita. They were married and had a son, who was named Narasimha after his father. After Narasimha's death, Chenchita built a temple in his honor, and it is said that the temple still stands today.

> Another story says that Narasimha stayed on Earth for 100 years, during which time he helped the people of the land by curing their ailments and protecting them from harm. He was eventually called back to the divine abode, but his legacy lives on in the hearts and minds of the people who worship him.

The popular religious lecturer Dushyanth Seidar says he stayed only for a short duration.

Does scripture record how he returned to Vaikuntha like Rama and Krishna?

Comment: He got prahlada crowned immediately and disappeared.